# Typescript default function parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am a super newbie to Typescript so sorry for a dumb question...

I want to write a function that takes arguments like below

```
export const AutoComplete = async (
    str: string,
    functionList?: GetAllFunctions()
) => {

}
```

`GetAllFunctions()` is something that returns an array and need to be the default for `functionList` but I could also do something like

`AutoComplete ('foo', ['foo', 'bar'...])`

What would be the correct way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed the default value expression where the type annotation for `functionList` should be:

```
export const AutoComplete = async (str: string, functionList: string[] = GetAllFunctions()) => {
//                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                              arg name      type       default value
};
```

The `:` says "Here's the type for functionList". The `=` says "this is the default value for functionList".

You can also have *only* a default value (no type annotation), like this

```
export const AutoComplete = async (str: string, functionList = GetAllFunctions()) => {
//                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                              arg name       default value
};
```

... or only a type annotation (no default value), like this:

```
export const AutoComplete = async (str: string, functionList: string[]) => {
//                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
//                                              arg name      type    
};
```

In any case, the meaning of `:` vs. `=` in the function signature remains the same.

Comment: just curious how it would look if it was an array of objects?

Comment: @prgrmr Do you mean the type of an argument? In that case it'll be just `object[]` for _any_ object. Alternatively you can use a literal type, e.g. `{ key: string }[]`, or reference an existing named type / interface: `MyTypeOrInterface[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
export const AutoComplete = async (
  str: string,
  functionList = GetAllFunctions()
) => {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the function signature you are looking for:

```
export const AutoComplete = async (str: string, functionList: string[] = GetAllFunctions()) => {};
```